# Java installer for Swing based project

Tags: java, installation, izpack

I worked on a Java project in which web services are used, values are to be modified in registry and there are some DLLs to be register with system. there are some environment variables to set, at the time of installation, keeping in mind these requirements , which Java installer is best, i also need a installer which is platform independent as my Java project is platform independent.

I think i may use [IzPack](http://izpack.org/)

but i think you guys can help me better and suggest me an installer.

Comment: How does "there are some DLLs to be register with system" relate to " my Java project is platform indpendent"?

Comment: @Kos: maybe it can work in the absence of the said DLLs?

Comment: yes it can work in the absence of DLLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use IzPack, its a great tool which bundles your installer in a jar. platform independent and with the possibility to only use some routines when special conditions a present. For example, only install DLL on Windows, mess with the registry (Custom Action) and so on.

I always enjoyed using IzPack and suggest you should give it a try.
The doc is also a great resource for the possibilities [Doc](http://izpack.org/documentation/)

Answer (score 3):

If a commercial product is an option, you could take a look at [install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html), but I can't say anything about it.

IzPack seems to be the only open source Java installer that's still being actively developed. I've recently used it myself, and it has a lot of powerful features, but is not easy to get started with. There's a lot of documentation that describes some things in great detail, but unfortunately no simple "how to" for the most common case. Expect to spend a lot of time on trial-and-error.